# ASP.net membership webforms admin userlist

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership

I have been using the ASP.net membership system, with code such as:

```
<asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" 
                BorderStyle="Solid" 
                BackColor="#F7F7DE" 
                BorderWidth="1px"
                BorderColor="#CCCC99" 
                Font-Size="10pt" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" 
                CreateUserText="Create a new user..."
                CreateUserUrl="register.aspx" 
                HelpPageUrl="help.aspx"
                PasswordRecoveryUrl="getPass.aspx" 
                UserNameLabelText="Username:" 
                OnLoggingIn="OnLoggingIn"
                OnLoginError="OnLoginError" >
                <TitleTextStyle Font-Bold="True" 
                    ForeColor="#FFFFFF" 
                    BackColor="#6B696B">
                </TitleTextStyle>
            </asp:Login>
```

Works great!  But from within my admin area I would like a pages list of users, with the ability to edit the users settings.

Is there a built in control for this (I rmember seeing one but I cant find it), or do I have to code it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no standard built-in control for doing this. You need to code it yourself or search for custom controls.

However you maybe looking for ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool and it's security tab. This  is not a control but set of pages coming with .net framework. You can run this tool from Project menu of Visual Studio (Project - ASP.NET Configuration) or by adding the WebAdmin.axd file to the end of the application root URL (for example http://server/application/WebAdmin.axd). For security reasons you can use this tool only from computer where your application is hosted.